# How to use activeIndex in Swiper JS, how to make second slider active, not the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

```
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiperEvent", {
    slidesPerView: "auto",
    centeredSlides: true, 
    spaceBetween: 115,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs, you can use `initialSlide`:

https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-initialSlide

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiperEvent", { 
  slidesPerView: "auto",
  centeredSlides: true,
  spaceBetween: 115,
  pagination: { el: ".swiper-pagination", clickable: true, }, 
  navigation: { nextEl: ".swiper-button-next", prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev" }, 
  initialSlide: 1 // HERE
})
```